# $_session [ ' ' ] = array ( )

Tags: php

A onde fica arquivado os dados salvos na session?

Mais uma dúvida, por quê esse código é assim

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$id])){
        $_SESSION['itens'][$id] = 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['itens'][$id] =1;
    }
```

Eu apenas copiei esse código de outras pessoas, mas, não sei o motivo deles seres junto asssim [ ' itens' ] [ $id ]

Abraço, desde já agradeço .

Comment: Se não existir a chave `$_SESSION['itens'][$id]` o código cria ela e atribui o valor `1`, caso exista atribui o valor `1` também  :)

Comment: Amigo, tente ser um pouco mais explicativo na sua pergunta. Qual a finalidade da função que voce quer utilizar? Altere também o título para algo que possamos compreender

Comment: da uma lida em: `session_save_path` disponivel em: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php

Answer (score 1):

O motivo de a variável ter duas chaves juntas como no seu exemplo `$_SESSION['itens'][$id]` significa que a variável `$_SESSION` é um array e um dos campos desse array é `itens`. A variável então `$_SESSION['itens']` é também um array e contem dentro dela alguns campos, sendo um deles o valor contido na variável `$id`.